# Finding Capacity Remaining In An iPhone Battery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, battery

Does anyone know how (if possible) I can find out how much capacity (mAh) is remaining in an iPhone battery at any given time?

[image]

Something like the program above?

Is there a value stored in a plist somewhere??

Comment: Aside from the fact that it would make no sense to waste power writing something like that to a property list file repeatedly, doesn't the phone take care of displaying the battery status for the user already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

couple ways,

- pre 3.0 sdk: http://blog.coriolis.ch/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/
- with 3.0 sdk - the [UIDevice batteryLevel property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620042-batterylevel) (example: http://blog.coriolis.ch/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/#comment-4607)

to gauge the mAh you could check the battery level over time using that method.

3.0 has added an event to do that:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(batteryChanged:)
name:@”UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification” object:device];
```

in general, measuring the open circuit voltage or current is used to gauge the state of charge by the hardware. the capacity of the bat will shrink over time, so 100% will indicate no more charge can be stored, even tho the capacity is lower than a new iphone battery.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am using the pre 3.0 sdk method at the moment and this returns the percent of charge remaining. I want to know mAh left i.e 750mAh. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the iPhone automatically re-calibrate and display an appropriate percentage depending on the age of your battery?

Comment: Thanks for that I understand much better now!

Answer (score 2):

The [UIDevice API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice) includes a property relating to [battery level](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620042-batterylevel).